# Javascript assigning prototype confusion

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypejs

```
var object1 = {
    name: "abc",
    age: 21
}

var Object2 = function() {}
Object2.prototype = object1;
Object2.prototype.hello = function() {
    console.log("Hello");
}

var obj = Object.create(object1);
for (var prop in obj) {
    console.log(prop + ": " + obj[prop]);
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
name: abc
age: 21
hello: function () {
    console.log("Hello");
}
```

Obj is created by setting its prototype as object1, which doesn't have the 'hello' function, so why is it listed in the output? If I comment out 'Object2.prototype = object1;', the 'hello' function no longer shows in the output. I don't see how obj and Object2 are connected. Can anyone please explain what's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After this line...

```
Object2.prototype = object1;
```

... both `Object2.prototype` and `object1` refer to the same object. Hence this line...

```
Object2.prototype.hello = function() { // ...
```

... assigns a new property to the object referred by `object1`.

> I don't see how `obj` and `Object2` are connected.

With `var obj = Object.create(object1)`, you create an object which `__proto__` property points to `object1`. The latter, as we established, is actually the same object `Object2.prototype` points to.

---

> I.e setting Object2.prototype to an object without them both referring to the same object?

If you only want `Object2.prototype` to copy properties from `object1`, just [clone an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object).

Comment: Ohh okay. Thank you. Is there any any way to avoid this from happening? I.e setting Object2.prototype to an object without them both referring to the same object?